# How I can use Xuggler with Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework, xuggle

I was trying to use Xuggler ( http://www.xuggle.com/ ) with play! framework. I'm using Mac OSX and also created the `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` file with xuggler path. I also set these in my `~/.bashrc`

```
export XUGGLE_HOME=/usr/local/xuggler
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME/lib
```

I put all the jars in the `/lib` folder of my play! application and updated the `dependencies.yml` like the following -

```
require:
    - play
    - provided -> xuggle-xuggler

repositories:
    - provided:
        type:       local
        artifact:   "${application.path}/lib/xuggle-xuggler.jar"
        contains:
            - provided -> *
```

BTW, I also ran `play dependencies` and it is still giving this error -

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError occured : no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error points to a problem with linking to a DLL file, so I checked the Xuggler docs for installation, and it had a section specifically to deal with this type of error.

http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Installation_Questions

It has the following, as a set of instructions you should follow to solve the error.

> What's up with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?
>
> It means that Java can't find the Xuggler native library. Check the
>   following:
>
> - Did you install the Xuggler?
> - Is the environment variable XUGGLE_HOME defined and
>     pointing to your Xuggler install directory (usually C:\Program
>     Files\Xuggle on Windows or /usr/local on Linux/Mac)?
> - If you installed
>     on Windows, did you reboot after you installed?
> - Does your PATH
>     environment variable include %XUGGLE_HOME%\bin on Windows or
>     $XUGGLE_HOME/bin on Linux/Mac?
> - Does your PATH environment variable
>     include %XUGGLE_HOME%\lib on Windows?
> - Does your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>     environment variable include $XUGGLE_HOME/lib on Linux?
> - Does your
>     DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environmentvariable include $XUGGLE_HOME/lib on Mac
>     OS-X?
> - Are you using a 32-bit Java JVM, but a 64-bit version of
>     Xuggler? Or a 64-bit version of the Java JVM but a 32-bit version of
>     Xuggler? Unfortunately that won't work. You need to make sure that you
>     match the "bitness" of each release. Sorry.

Comment: Didn't I answer all the questions above?

Comment: No. I assume point 1 is true, what about 7 and 8? Have you checked your PATH variable?

Comment: about 7, please check what I exported in my `~/.bashrc` and about 8, well I didn't mention that but I've already went through the xuggle wiki. Anyway, thanks for your precious time :)

Comment: 7 talks about DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, you have exported  LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The YD prefix appears to be specific for Mac OS X. If this is not the answer, then I would suggest trying to run an example outside of Play to determine if it is Play or your Xuggle install/config.

Comment: Well example outside play! worked because it (eclipse) uses `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`. Thanks, It was not working because of the DY prefix (not YD) :)